# Question about vacuous truth of a statement on reals?

Tags: logic, proof-writing, induction

So I am trying to prove the following statement by induction on $m$:

If for some non zero real $\{a_i\}$ and non zero real $\{x_i\}$ the following holds:
If
$$\forall n \in \mathbb{Z^{+}}. \sum_{i=1}^{m}a_i x_{i}^{n} = 0$$

then it is necessarily true that $\forall i,j. x_i = x_j$.

Let's call this  hypothesis to be $H(m)$.

In my proof by induction I started with the base case $m=2$, because I am confused about the case $m=1$. Can I say that $H(1)$ is vacuously true ?

EDIT: So I have already proved the statement for $m \geq 2$, but if I can be sure of the base case as $m=1$, then I will be happier. Also, $x_i$'s are not variables but rather given non zero reals.

Comment: Are the $x_j$'s the indeterminates of a polynomial? If yes, what is it supposed to mean that they are 'non zero'?

Comment: @arnett thanks for that I have edited the question to make it clearer.

Comment: @Logic No I think you are right, the way I framed it seemed like I wanted to fill that blank. But I have changed the question a bit now, is it clearer what I am asking ?

Comment: @tomasz $\{a_i\}$ and $\{x_i\}$ are non zero reals

Comment: If $m=1$ then you have $a_{1}x_{1}^n=0$

Comment: @tomasz, my solution is a generalisation of the answer provided [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4383786/142677).

Comment: @Logic I have that $a_1 x_1^{n} = 0$, now since I have only one $x_i$, then does it mean that $\forall i,j . x_i = x_j$ is vacuously true ?

Comment: @logic could you elaborate a bit please, I just want to be sure ? So this is a "vacuous truth" right ?

Comment: Why vacuously true? The only possible value for $i,j $ is $1$ so it’s true.

Comment: @logic Aaaah yes! that makes sense. But will that fact that no such value exist make it vacuous ? I am sorry i just want to be sure ! Also I will happily accept this as an answer if you would like ?. EDIT: After more though, I still think it may be a vacuous truth. I am testing $P -> Q$, now, when $m=1$ then $P$ is false, hence making the statement true. Isnt that the definition of vaccuous truth ?

Comment: P: For some non zero $\{a_i\}$ and $\{x_i\}$ $\forall n. \sum_{i=1}^{m} a_ix_i^{n} = 0$ and  $Q: \forall i,j.  x_i = x_j$. Now, $P(1)$ is $a_1x_1^{n}=0$, which is just not possible. Hence it is false. Hence, $P(1) \rightarrow Q(1)$ is vaccuously true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your statement if I understand correctly is:$$[\{x_i\}\not=0 \land\{a_{i}\}\not=0\land\forall n \in \mathbb{Z^{+}}. \sum_{i=1}^{m}a_i x_{i}^{n} = 0]\implies \forall i,j. x_i = x_j$$
 Call the first statement in the implication $P$, now if $m=1$then $a_{1}x_{1}^n=0$ then we have $a_{1}=0$ or $x_{1}=0$, so if $m=1$ then $P$ is false hence the whole statement is vacuously true.